# 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present' error

Tags: c#, code-behind

I've got this code block:

```
using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(str2))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation WHERE CUST_NUM = @CNum", con2))
    {
        con2.Open();

        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNum", TBAccountNum.Text);

        using (SqlDataReader DT2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // If the SQL returns any records, process the info
            if (DT2.HasRows)
            {
                // If there's a BusinessID (aka Business Type), fill it in
                string BizID = (DT2["Business_ID"].ToString());
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BizID))
                {
                    DDLBustype.SelectedValue = BizID;
                }
            }
        }
        con2.Close();
    }
}
```

When it gets to the line

```
string BizID = (DT2["Business_ID"].ToString());
```

it throws an error:

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Why would it get past `if (DT2.HasRows)` if there was no data?

Answer (score 5):

You need to call

```
if(DT2.Read()) 
 ....
```

before proceding to read data from a DataReader.

The [HasRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx) tells you only that the SqlDataReader contains data, but the SqlDataReader loads one record at time from the connection. Thus every tentative to extract the data from the SqlDataReader should be preceded by a call to [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) to position the SqlDataReader on the first record returned through the connection.

And, because the Read method returns true if the call has been able to read a record, you could replace the call to HasRows with something like this

```
    using (SqlDataReader DT2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // If the SQL returns any records, process the info
        while(DT2.Read())
        {
            // If there's a BusinessID (aka Business Type), fill it in
            string BizID = (DT2["Business_ID"].ToString());
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BizID))
            {
                DDLBustype.SelectedValue = BizID;
            }
        }
    }
```

By the way, if it is possible to have a NULL for BusinessID then you need a different test to avoid exception problems

```
int bizColIndex = DT2.GetOrdinal("Business_ID");
string BizID = (DT2.IsDBNull(bizColIndex) ? string.Empty : DT2.GetString(bizColIndex));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BizID))
{
    DDLBustype.SelectedValue = BizID;
}
```